# How to get all the latest updated posts (published, unpublished and promoted/dark) from stream table via FQL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to retrieve via FQL all the posts of a page using the stream table, ordered by updated_time.
With "all" I mean every kind, published, unpublished and promoted/dark posts as our customer posts tens of promoted and targeted posts per day.

This is needed so I can later fetch the comments on them.
I can't miss any comment, even if someone comments on a post when it's unpublished (unpublished posts are still reachable via direct link).

The problem is that older posts, when commented, are not returned even if the updated_time attribute gets updated.

This is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT post_id, is_hidden, is_published, promotion_status, message, updated_time, created_time, comments 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = me() 
  AND (is_published = 1 OR is_published = 0)
  AND (is_hidden = 1 OR is_hidden = 0)
  AND (updated_time != created_time) 
  AND updated_time > #{(Time.now - 5.days).to_i}
ORDER BY updated_time DESC
LIMIT 250
```

Running this query I correctly get the latest 250 created posts, ordered by updated_time.

My concern is that Facebook takes the latest 250 posts (by creation date) and then applies the filters from the where clause.

In fact if I create a comment on an older post of one day ago, let's say could be the 270th, it gets an updated updated_time and I'm able to retrieve it directly via its ID with this query:

```
SELECT post_id, is_hidden, is_published, promotion_status, message, updated_time, created_time, comments 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = me() 
  AND (is_published = 1 OR is_published = 0)
  AND (is_hidden = 1 OR is_hidden = 0)
  AND (updated_time != created_time) 
  AND post_id = 'xxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
```

**but it isn't returned by the previous query.**

Someone knows a better way to retrieve every kind of post from a page, ordered by updated time?

Comment: As said by this post the stream table is the right one: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/23/new-marketing-tools-for-pages/ Graph API's Page object instead doesn't provide a way to sort by updated_time

Comment: It seems this is a known issue: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/337535839676314/